# Other than via configuration in /etc/yum.repos.d, where else can a repository be configured?

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum

Helping out someone who inherited his environment. He wants to disable some repositories. This is an anonymized output of his `yum repolist`:

```
luke@server1 $ sudo yum repolist
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
repo id                        repo name                                                 status
acme-rhel-x86-64-server-5      ACME Packages (v.5 for 64-bit)                                 1
epel                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64             7,745
rhel-x86_64-server-5           Red Hat Enterprise Linux (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64)         16,133
rhn-tools-rhel-x86_64-server-5 Red Hat Network Tools for RHEL Server (v.5 64-bit x86_64)    564
repolist: 24,443
```

However, doing the following yields no results:

```
luke@server1 $ grep -ri acme /etc/yum.repos.d /etc/yum/pluginconf.d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it is using the rhnplugin to access "RHN Classic." To disable a repository (unsubscribe from a channel) you use the [`rhn-channel`](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/57504)command or the web interface at http://rhn.redhat.com/

Answer (score 0):

While `.repo` files are usually placed in `/etc/yum.repos.d` you can specify a different directory by using `reposdir=xxx` in`/etc/yum.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're registered to Satellite (you have a subscription to rhn-tools so I'm betting this is the case), the ACME repo is probably a child channel your system is subscribed to in which case it's made available to `yum` by way of the `rhnplugin` module which enumerates all the channels you're subscribed to and presents to yum as if they're repositories.

The name of the repo does look like a Satellite channel ID as well but that's just a guess based on how the name is structured.

You can confirm with the `rhn-channel` command:

```
root@xxxxxxlp03 ~ $ rhn-channel -l
epel6-64bit
rhel-x86_64-server-6
rhn-tools-rhel-x86_64-server-6
```